# What seeds should I use in `invoke_signed()` for PDA derived via `create_with_seed()`

Tags: rust, pda, seed

I have a PDA generated with:

```
const SEED: &str = "My Seed";
let pda = Pubkey::create_with_seed(program_id, SEED, &owner_id).unwrap();
```

Where `program_id` and `owner_id` are some fixed `Pubkey`'s.

I want to call this:

```
invoke_signed(
    &my_instruction,
    &[...], \\Slice of AccountInfos, pda is among them
    &[&[...]],\\Seeds for accounts to be signed
)
```

Then I pass `SEED.as_bytes()`a as a seed, I get `InvalidSeed` error.
What to use in this field?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't working for you because `create_with_seed` doesn't generate a PDA! Use `Pubkey::find_program_address` if you want that.

So your code will look like:

```
const SEED: &[u8] = b"My Seed";
let (pda, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[SEED], program_id);
```

Comment: Then what is the purpose of `CreateWithSeed` instruction?

Comment: new questions deserve new posts